# django admin custom css only in changeview

Tags: django, django-admin

I need to have bootstrap css in django admin, but only in change view, not list view. If I use

```
    class Media:
    css = {
        'all': ('tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput.css', 'bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.css',)
    }
```

It affects both views and breaks some elements in list view. How can I do that?

Comment: If the answer is good, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: It works, but I'm searching for a better solution. Overriding a template affects all adminModels, but I want to have that css only in one adminModel's changeView

Comment: If you check that link from django documentation you will see you can have it for specific model. You did not share the model path of your code but let's say your model named FooModel is in package Foo, the correct path would be {templates_dir}/admin/foo/foomodel/change_list.html

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to override change_list template by your own. Create folder called `admin` in your templates folder. Then if you want to have it global effect, create `change_list.html` file there.

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% block extrastyle %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "/css/your_style.css" %}">
{% endblock %}
```

EDIT:
If you have model FooModel in package Foo, where you want to apply this css, place the file to `{template_dir}/admin/foo/foomodel/change_list.html`, if you want it for whole package `{template_dir}/admin/foo/change_list.html`

Comment: more reference here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#set-up-your-projects-admin-template-directories